# Averaging Results Across Regressions due to Periodicity/Overlaps

Tags: regression, prediction

Given data that arrives at a daily frequency, I aggregated it to a weekly frequency, and estimated an OLS regression on it. Given that there are roughly 5 trading days per week, I can construct 5 different OLS models using 5 different starting points. For example - one model uses returns from Monday-Monday, the next Tuesday-Tuesday, and so on.

Assuming I believe there are no seasonal effects (e.g. models trained using Monday-Monday returns should be no different than Tuesday-Tuesday), is there a correct way to combine the predictions/coefficients of these 5 (or in the general case, N) models? I am inclined to think quick and simple averaging of coefficients would work. In that case, is there a proper way to combine the standard errors and residual standard errors across models? I ask because I am interested in constructing confidence/predictive intervals for forecasts. I hesitate to estimate the model using the full dataset, because this will cause overlaps in my endogenous variable, and I am not well equipped/don't know how to deal with that.

Of course this question could be asked more generally for any (non-linear) kind of model, but it seems like OLS/linear models would have the most hope for a theoretically sound procedure/heuristic.

Comment: Cross Validated has some related threads: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overlapping-data, e.g. [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/553881).

Comment: Thanks @RichardHardy - I'll be sure to read through them and the references you posted in your answer.

Comment: I think it is enough to read the relevant sections of Hayashi's textbook.

Comment: I was going through my old answers and noticed this one was not accepted. Do you perhaps need further clarification?

Answer (score 1):

The efficient point estimator would be OLS on all 5-day periods, even though there will be a lot of overlapping. You would need to adjust the standard errors for autocorrelation by using robust standard errors. No model averaging is needed. Here are some references:

1. Hayashi, Fumio. *[Econometrics](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691010182/econometrics)*. Princeton University Press (2011).  See sections 6.6-6.8.
2. Britten‐Jones, Mark, Anthony Neuberger, and Ingmar Nolte. *"Improved inference in regression with overlapping observations."* Journal of Business Finance & Accounting 38.5‐6 (2011): 657-683.
3. Harri, Ardian, and B. Wade Brorsen. *"The overlapping data problem."* Available at SSRN 76460 (1998).
4. Hansen, Lars Peter, and Robert J. Hodrick. *"Forward exchange rates as optimal predictors of future spot rates: An econometric analysis."* The Journal of Political Economy (1980): 829-853.